# Getting the value of option and display it on the select box

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I know this was asked many times, I'm looking for a simple solution.

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>    
<option value="2">Two</option>  
</select>
```

When a user select an option let's say One the select box would display the numerical 1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a numeral for the display option on each?
e.g. `<option value="1">1</option>`
(and take the inline javascript out entirely).

example: http://jsfiddle.net/79xvY/

Comment: That is just an example I'm getting the datas from database w/c have long characters but have an abbreviation w/c I'm going to put in the value.

Comment: To insert a value from a database you'd just write the reference out inline using your server-side language as you wrote out the page HTML. If you were changing the value dynamically, I imagine you'd use the AJAX callback function linked to .onreadystatechange as a trigger to update the <option> innerhtml as @The4thIceman references in the other answer.  Getting the <option> reference may be tricky - you can return the <option> current value using document.form.<name> but setting it dynamically may require assigning an id and using document.getElementById('<id>').

Answer (score 0):

This will set the actual innerHTML value of the select box, if that is what your goal is

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML=this.value">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>    
    <option value="2">Two</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about but when a user select the options text are replaced by the value.

Comment: This does do that, it replaces the innerHTML of the option to whatever the value of that option was